# How do I know when an async aws lambda ends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

It will be easier to understand if you look at the image:

[image: Flow diagram]

**I am coding using AWS Lambda in node.js.**

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

const payload = 'hello from lambda 1';

const params = {
    FunctionName: 'lambda2',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
};

const LambdaPromise = (params) => lambda.invoke(params).promise();

const responseFromLambda2 = await LambdaPromise(params);

return responseFromLambda2; //this should return {StatusCode: 202, Payload: ''}
};
```

I tried referring to the code above, but it failed.

`A lambda` invokes `B lambda`. And `B lambda` invokes many `C lambdas` asynchronously.

How do I know that `B lambda` ends with `C lambdas`?

I can't do this so `Lambda A` doesn't know if `lambda B` did its job properly.

Comment: Sounds like B should just await for all of its C invocations to finish, or am I missing something?

Comment: You would want to use Step Functions for this, instead of having one Lambda invoke another.

Comment: @AKX You're right to wonder how the B lambda waits for the C lambdas to finish.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I want to use step functions, but I have already created a backend server.

Comment: "I want to use step functions, but I have already created a backend server" This statement lists two things that are not relevant to each other. You're obviously using a bunch of Lambda functions that need to be coordinated, and that can best be done with Step Functions. If you also have a backend server, that is irrelevant to this specific problem.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I understood the step function correctly. Thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you describe is ideal for [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html):

> **Step Functions** is a serverless orchestration service that lets you **combine AWS Lambda functions** and other AWS services to build business-critical applications. Through Step Functions' graphical console, you see your application’s workflow as a series of event-driven steps.

[image: AWS Step Functions]